# Context parameter for an Intent constructor

Tags: java, android, object, inheritance

**I am completely new to android development.** In fact, I am building my first application after the hello world application, following this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

and I have come accross the term Context for the first time. I have opened the API for the class but the description (given as follows) given there is not understandable for me at all.

"Interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc."

**1. Can somebody tell me in the simplest terms ever what a context is.
    Please tell something a complete noob and a beginner can undertand.**

1. I have come accross this term in the explanation (in the tutorial i have given a link to) of the statement which builds an intent i.e. Intent intent= new intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

and the explanation says that "this" is used where a context is required because Activity is a subclass of Context.

To the best of my knowledge of the java programming language, this is used to refer to the current object. The current object here is an object of Activity.

Now, since Activity is a subclass of Context, so are they using the object of Activity (referred here by the this keyword) in place of an object of the super class Context's object? BUT ISN'T IT THAT A SUB CLASS OBJECT CAN NOT BE IMPLICITLY CASTED TO A SUPER CLASS OBJECT?

**My QUESTION IN A NUTSHELL (if the above question confuses you) IS THAT WHY ARE THEY USING THIS KEYWORD IN PLACE OF A CONTEXT (i.e. super class of this Activity class) OBJECT?**

Comment: you are wrong. The cast from a derived  class to the super class is always safe. If you try to cast a base class to a derived class is it no safe

Comment: Your question "why are they using `this` keyword in place of a `Context`" is flawed: `this` is an `Activity` and therefore it _is_ a `Context`. The receiver just doesn't care whether the concrete object that you pass in is an `Activity` or a `ZorkPlong` object, as long as it supports all the things a `Context` does.

Comment: But what is a contect?

Answer (score 1):

> BUT ISN'T IT THAT A SUB CLASS OBJECT CAN NOT BE IMPLICITLY CASTED TO A
>   SUPER CLASS OBJECT?

Once I was reading **Bruce Eckel's *Thinking in Java***. He describes the concept of casting both ways, their usefulness and requirements. The thing that differed in his book as compared to other authors(many of them) is the way he links the concept to real world while not getting much verbose. Here is what he said in this context:

The casting from Sub-Class to a Super-Class is safe because, the Sub class at least has the interface that super class provided to extend(of course that is public). So while casting from sub class to super class, you can safely call all the methods common to them but doing it the other way around(super to sub) gives you the unsafe handle to call all the extra methods not available with the parent class if there are any.

This corrected concept of yours will answer your second question,

> WHY ARE THEY USING THIS KEYWORD IN PLACE OF A CONTEXT

**P.S:** Don't use UPPERCASE font to post normal words. We are sound and patient enough to read it normally and think of something sensible to answer.